# Go through a checked listbox and check all items C#

Tags: c#, loops, checkedlistbox

I need to loop through a checked listbox, and for each of the items in it, I need to check them (basically like a "select all" function).

Is there a basic example you could give me to help me out please?

Comment: probably you need to explain more...where do these check boxes reside...in a grid? repeater? List?...please add more detail...

Comment: I agree with NiK .. there are many ways depending on location.. if it is on a webpage.. jQuery is the easiest way :D

Answer (score 22):

Use [`SetSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx) and interate through all the `Items`

```
// Loop through and set all to selected.
for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
{
   listBox1.SetSelected(x, true);
}
```

To check the items, use [`SetItemChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx)

```
// Loop through and set all to checked.
for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
{
   listBox1.SetItemChecked(x, true);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this work but only if the line is changed to:
listBox1.SetItemChecked(x, true);
as it is a checked listbox

Answer (score 5):

You can look through all the items as ListItems:

```
foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    li.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Anonymous added: (ListItem will require a reference to System.Web.UI.WebControls)